# Need some bug identification with Bit Manipulation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

The problem is `SegmentOFF`. For example if `DATA[18] = 0x10` after calling `SegmentON` and I want to clear 6th bit of `DATA[18]`. Calling `SegmentOFF` clears all the bit and ends up `DATA[18] = 0x00`

What is wrong with the code.

```
unsigned char DATA[24];     
unsigned int Segment2BitMap[48] = 
{
    0x0000, 0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0003, 0x0004, 0x0005, 0x0006, 0x0007,
    0x0204, 0x0300, 0x0302, 0x0307, 0x0600, 0x0601, 0x0602, 0x0603,
    0x0604, 0x0605, 0x0606, 0x0607, 0x0804, 0x0900, 0x0902, 0x0907,
    0x0C00, 0x0C01, 0x0C02, 0x0C03, 0x0C04, 0x0C05, 0x0C06, 0x0C07,
    0x0E04, 0x0F00, 0x0F02, 0x0F07, 0x1200, 0x1201, 0x1202, 0x1203,
    0x1204, 0x1205, 0x1206, 0x1207, 0x1404, 0x1500, 0x1502, 0x1507    
};

void SegmentON(unsigned char Number)
   {
    unsigned int Data = Segment2BitMap[Number];
    unsigned char UpperByte = (Data/256); //upper byte
    unsigned char LowerByte = (Data%256 & 0x07); //lower byte
    DATA[UpperByte] |= (0x01<<LowerByte);
}

void SegmentOFF(unsigned char Number)
{
    unsigned int Data = Segment2BitMap[Number];
    unsigned char UpperByte = (Data/256); //upper byte
    unsigned char LowerByte = (Data%256 & 0x07); //lower byte
    DATA[UpperByte] &= (0x01<<LowerByte);
}

int main()
{
    SegmentON(40);
    SegmentOFF(42);
}
```

Comment: Try to do it on paper first. When you get it right there then it's easy to implement it in code.

Comment: In your `SegmentOFF` function, you want all bits to be `1` *except* the one your are turning off. Right now you only set a single bit to `1`, so you clear all other bits. Just invert the value before applying the bitwise & operator, i.e. `DATA[UpperByte] &= ~(0x01<<LowerByte)`.

Comment: Not related to the bug, but that `/` and `%` are pretty ugly and obfuscating. If you'd done it the normal way, you would immediately see that `data & 0xFF & 7` is the same thing as `data & 7` so you could make it a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
 1010 & 0101 == 0000
```

If you want to clear a specific bit and the rest should not be changed you have to invert it.

For 8 bit:

```
var &= (1<<2)^0xFF
```

This would set the 3rd least significant bit `(1<<2) == 0x04` and then invert it with xor everything with ones

And then you apply that mask to var to set the 3rd bit to zero and the rest stays unchanged

This would be

```
var = var & 0b11111011
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I mostly do ruby but the bit-wise operators look the same. (thus I'm assuming they are the same)

Lets work with a random number say 201. The binary representation is as follows:
1100 1001

To turn a bit on you simply do an OR operation.

201 |= 1<<2

The machine then bit shifts 0000 0001 2 steps to the left creating 0000 0100 and then makes an OR operation, if either of the numbers has a 1 at the nth position the resulting number will have a 1 at the same position.

1100 1001 # first input

0000 0100 # second input

1100 1101 # output => 209

So far so good, but when you try to set a bit to 0 using the AND operator something goes wrong. 
201 &= 1<<2

Same as before but now it performs an AND operation instead. If the number share a 1 at the nth position the resulting number will have a 1 at that same position.

1100 1001 # first input

0000 0100 # second input

0000 0000 # output => 0

This happens because they have no common 1s. This can be solved in 2 ways. (both using the XOR operation)

The 'conditional' way.

```
if 209&(1<<2) != 0
  209 ^= 1<<2
end
```

This code will do the following. if 201 and 1<<2 (8) is not equal to 0 then perform an exclusive or operation. In this case it is not equal to 0 so it will do as follows. Wherever the bits are the same it will put a 0 and where they differ it will put a 1.

1100 1101 # first input (209)

0000 0100 # second input (8)

1100 1001 # output => 201

The 'pure bit-wise' solution.

209&(255^(1<<2))

This will generate the following operation.

1100 1101 # first input (209)

1111 1011 # second input number (247)

1100 1001 # output => 201

We end up doing one extra bit operation, but we also loose the conditional. So it should be a *bit* faster. Get it **bit**, hehe. The code here can't directly be implemented in c, but the principal should be the same.

PS Your definition of the lower byte looks a bit odd, you are aware that it will only return the first 3 bits, right?

Hope it helps.